# Помогите определите максимальное значение

Tags: java, java-8

Задача :

> В первой строке содержится количество элементов num, В следующей строке заданы x действительных чисел - элементы последовательности, значения которых не превышают по модулю 100. Надо чтоб ответ выдал максимальное число если будет "-" Math.abs делаем положетельное число и если она больше то пусть покажет

Проблема: Не показывает максимальное число.

Код:

```
Scanner sh = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = sh.nextInt();

double x = 0;
double num2 = 0;
double num3 = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    x = sh.nextDouble();
    num2 = Math.abs(x);
    num2 = Math.max(i, num2);
    if(num2 > 0) {
       num3=Math.max(0, num2)            
    }  
}

System.out.printf("%.2f", num3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код запутан и плохо понятен. Строчка `num2 = Math.max(i, num2);` делает непонятно что. Вычеркиваем. Переменная `num3` не нужна, как и if-блок. Сократив и упростив получим такое:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sh = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sh.nextInt();

    double x = 0, maxValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        x = sh.nextDouble();
        x = Math.abs(x);
        maxValue = Math.max(x, maxValue);
    }
    System.out.printf("%.2f", maxValue);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , я в переменных запутался ;)

Answer (score 1):

может поменять подход?

```
Scanner sh = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sh.nextInt();
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) numbers.add(sh.nextDouble());
numbers.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).max()
    .ifPresent(value -> System.out.printf("%.2f", value));
```